# Insert mysql on foreign key id php

Tags: php, mysql, insert, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables, clubs and fixtures

**clubs**

```
id (int)
name (text)
```

**fixtures**

```
id (int)
hometeam (int, foreign key to clubs id)
awayteam (int, foreign key to clubs id)
datetime (datetime)
```

Each fixtures record uses an ID for the `hometeam` and `awayteam` as per the foreign key relationship.

I need to do an insert into the `fixtures` table, but I only have the `hometeam` name not the `hometeam` id. Is there a way of doing this through the foreign key relationship, without having to separately lookup the relevant id number?

Comment: The simple answer is no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with looking for foreign key value through a separate select query:

```
INSERT INTO `fixtures`
    VALUES ( NULL,
             (SELECT `id` FROM `clubs` WHERE `name` = 'NAME'),
             AWAYTEAM_ID,
             CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do in 2 steps:

- Insert hometeam in clubs table (get hometeamID if already have, otherwise  insert and get ID)
- Then insert into fixtures table

Comment: Sorry I think you might of misunderstood my question here. I have all the clubs already in the clubs table with ids. I wanted to find out if I can insert into the fixtures table with the club name instead of the club id, or if I would have to look up the club id to do an insert. I can get the club name from the id through the foreign key so hoped I could do the reverse

Comment: Ah ok, then you may get help from this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34868694/insert-into-a-table-after-getting-an-id-from-another-table