# Load Data Local Infile Based On Foreign Key Select

Tags: mysql, file, foreign-keys, mariadb

I am looking to insert data into a table based on a foreign key look up from a local data file but I am unsure of the syntax. I have a list of words:

```
jamba
fire
street
road
```

in a a file which I would like to insert into a table using

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$PATH'
    INTO TABLE b1 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n' 
    (SELECT id FROM dictionary
     WHERE dictionary.word='word-from-file');
```

To describe the project better: I am trying to create a table of foreign keys from a dictionary to layout a book, like using the dictionary entry number instead of words to order a book.

That is: the sentence `The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog` would, in the table, be `1024 891 26 51 75 521 1024 762 1024 641 45` (totally guessing) but where each number is an id number for a word in a dictionary.

The first table would be the dictionary:

```
Field    Type
id       word
word     varchar(128)
```

The second table would be the book, b1:

```
Field    Type
pos      int   #Position of the word, essentially an id
wid      int   #A foreign key corresponding to a dictionary.word
```

Case-Sensitivity matters. Don't and don't are two different words.

Essentially I am trying to perform the action explained in this SO answer from @revo: 
[Insert mysql on foreign key id php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50795607/insert-mysql-on-foreign-key-id-php) but using the fields in a local data file instead of a separate table.

Note: Case-sensitivity matters! I have defined the dictionary word field based on

```
CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin
```

Comment: You have two columns of type `int` in `b1` (the table you are trying to insert words from `$PATH`). It's clear what `wid` should take but `pos` is unclear. Besides, you are reading words and you don't have a column to store a word?

Comment: Yes. I want only numbers in `b1`. The `pos` is the position of the word in the book (1st position, 2nd position, 3rd...), the `wid` is the `id` of the `word` in the `dictionary`. "That is: the sentence 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog' would, in the table, be '1024 891 26 51 75 521 1024 762 1024 641 45' (totally guessing) but where each number is an `id` number for a `word` in a `dictionary`." (quoted from an added edit in the question)

Comment: So is `pos` an auto increment field?

Comment: Yes. `pos` is by auto increment so that it corresponds to `word` position in book.

Comment: Please check the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `SET` clause. Also take care of line terminators (`\r\n` in Windows OS):

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path-to-file' 
INTO TABLE `b1`
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(@word)
SET `wid` = (SELECT `id` FROM `DICTINARY` `d` WHERE BINARY `d`.`word` = @word);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without creating a temporary 'word' column?

Comment: I get an error 1242 'Subquery' returns more than 1 row. Also, I don't mean temporary table, I mean temporary column. My understanding is I have to have a column called 'word' in 'table'.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you. `word` should be renamed to your real column name in `table`.

Comment: Please show me the ``table`` structure which you are inserting words from file into it.

Comment: Added table structure, redefined table names for accuracy.

Comment: I'm getting 'ERROR 1242 (21000): subquery returns more than 1 row.' Apparently that defines a variable but it doesn't reset the variable?

Comment: Do you have duplicated words in `DICTINARY` table?

Comment: Well, yes if you're talking about case-insensitivity. There are cases of `Administration` and `administration`

Comment: Okay please check again.

Comment: Huzzah! It worked! But this is a long query. This is going to take forever for much longer books. I'll have to look into alternate methods. Perhaps a simple script for most commonly used words replacement can speed it up. Down the road. Thank you revo.

Comment: You're welcome. It wouldn't be that slow if you consider an index on `word` column.

Answer (score 0):

1. `LOAD` the new list into an extra table that has an extra column for the id, defaulted to `NULL`.
2. `INSERT .. SELECT .. WHERE .. NULL` to insert any new words into the dictionary.
3. Do a multi-table `UPDATE` to pull back the ids for all the words.  This goes into the extra column.
4. Proceed to do whatever else you need to do -- such as copy the data (using the `id` instead of `word`) into some other table.

I go into more detail [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization) .

Meanwhile, be sure to have the same `COLLATION` (eg, `utf8_bin`) on the `word` column in any tables where it exists.

It should be quite fast for your application *if* the collation matches *and* the dictionary has an index on `word`.

Mismatched collation leads to non-use of index, which will be terribly slow.